# how to implement AES in LoRa Module with Hardware Flow control using ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, hardware, wireless

I am working on project where I have to do  AES encryption of plain text  received through normal UART port of ESP8266 create a cipher text and sending it to LoRa module ([EByte E32 868T30D](http://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=189)) through Software Serial port and recieve on the other end decrypt and get the plain text back. the problem I am facing is when I try to sendlarge array of bytes more than 300 or so I am getting garbled values on the other end. I am well aware of the 512 byte limit in LoRa module and so I tried using Hardware flow control by AUX pin that is available. Eventhough I am not successfull in implementing a working code. I have a grey area in how to implement such a hardware flow control in ESP8266. since its my first time I am seeking for help from experts in this field. My project requires me to send about 10kB of data over LoRa with minimum possible delay between each 512 byte transmission
[image]

```
/*===========================================================================================================================================================================
   ---------------------------------------------------- ESP8266 EByte 32 Lora Encryption Test ----------------------------------------------------
   Author: Mister.B
   Date: 10 May 2020
   Objective: To test AES256 ECB Encryption on LoRa Modules
   Third-Party ibraries used:
   1) aes256 - https://github.com/qistoph/ArduinoAES256
  ===========================================================================================================================================================================*/
#include "aes256.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//EByte E32 Pin Configuration

#define M0 D5
#define M1 D6
#define AUX D2 // AUX HIGH means BUSY LOW means READY
#define RX_Pin D3
#define TX_Pin D4

//BaudRate Selection

#define E32_BAUD 9600
#define SERIAL_BAUD 9600

//AES Parameters
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048 //2kB buffer to store the values
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

//Timeout selection
#define UART_SERIAL_TIMEOUT 5000
#define E32_SERIAL_TIMEOUT 5000

//Debug Selection
#define DEBUG_CONSOLE true

//Class Instances
aes256_context ctxt;
SoftwareSerial E32(RX_Pin, TX_Pin);
//#define E32 Serial
//======Global Variables Declaration======
uint8_t key[] = {
  0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
  0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
  0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
  0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f
};
uint8_t data_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {};
int i = 0, in_count = 0, out_count = 0;
unsigned long last_packet_arrival = 0;

//MACROS
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) ((sizeof(arr))/(sizeof(arr[0])))
#if DEBUG_CONSOLE == true
#define DUMP(str,i,buf,sz){Serial.println(str);\
    for(i=0;i<sz;++i){if(buf[i]<0x10)Serial.print('0');Serial.print(char(buf[i]),HEX);}\
    Serial.println();}
#else
#define DUMP(str,i,buf,sz)
#endif


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD);
  E32.begin(E32_BAUD);
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AUX, INPUT);
  /*
     Setting Ebyte 32 in Normal Mode (M0=LOW and M1=LOW)
  */
  digitalWrite(M0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  DUMP("\nKey:", i, key, sizeof(key));
  aes256_init(&ctxt, key); // Send key for key scheduling
}
void loop()
{
  int frame_count = 0;
  out_count = 0;
  in_count = 0;
  last_packet_arrival = millis();
  /*
     RECEIVE DATA FROM EBYTE E32 LoRa
  */
  if (E32.available()) {
    out_count = 0;
    last_packet_arrival = millis();
    frame_count = (int)E32.read();
    while ((millis() - last_packet_arrival < E32_SERIAL_TIMEOUT) or (frame_count > out_count)) {
      out_count += E32.readBytes(data_buffer+out_count,58);
      if (out_count >= BUFFER_SIZE)Serial.printf("\n Input Buffer[%d] full :(", BUFFER_SIZE); break; //Prevent buffer overflow
    }
    Serial.printf("\nFc:%d", frame_count);
    frame_count = 0;
    Serial.printf("\nReceiveCount:%d\n", out_count);
    DUMP("\nRecived Data:", i, data_buffer, out_count);
    for (int n = 0; n <= (out_count / BLOCK_SIZE); n += BLOCK_SIZE)aes256_decrypt_ecb(&ctxt, data_buffer + n);
    DUMP("\nDecrypted Data:", i, data_buffer, out_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < out_count; i++)Serial.print((char)data_buffer[i]); yield();
    memset(data_buffer, 0x00, BUFFER_SIZE);
    out_count = 0;
  }
  /*
     RECEIVE DATA FROM UART Port
  */
  if (Serial.available()) {
    in_count=0;
    last_packet_arrival = millis();
    while ((millis() - last_packet_arrival) < UART_SERIAL_TIMEOUT) {
      in_count += Serial.readBytes(data_buffer + in_count, 58);
      if (in_count >= BUFFER_SIZE)Serial.printf("\n Output Buffer[%d] full :(", BUFFER_SIZE); break; // Prevent buffer overflow
    }
    /*
       Padding with zeros
    */
    if (in_count < 58) { // if Serial data entered is smaller than 58
      for (int i = in_count; i < 58; i++)data_buffer[i] = 0x00;
    }
    if (in_count > 58 && (in_count % 58 != 0)) { // if the Serial data is not multiple of 58 do padding with 0x00
      for (int i = in_count; i < in_count + (in_count % 58); i++)data_buffer[i] = 0x00;
    }
    Serial.printf("\nSendCount:%d", in_count);
    DUMP("\nData Entered:", i, data_buffer, in_count);
    //for (int n = 0; n <= (in_count / BLOCK_SIZE); n += BLOCK_SIZE)aes256_encrypt_ecb(&ctxt, data_buffer + n); // Encrypting whole data by 16 byte blocks
    //DUMP("\nEncrypted Data:", i, data_buffer, in_count);
    /*
       Add the length number of 512 byte in data frame
    */
    //uint8_t data_frame[BUFFER_SIZE + (BUFFER_SIZE % 58)] = {};
    //for (int i = 0; i <= BUFFER_SIZE; i++) data_frame[i + 1] = data_buffer[i];
    //data_frame[0] = (in_count / 58) + 1;
    //DUMP("\nSent Data:", i, data_frame, in_count + 1);
    /*
       Prevent buffer overflow in LoRa module using Hardware Flow control
    */
    uint8_t buff[58] = {};
//    for (int i = 0; i < (in_count / 464)+1 ; i++) //divide the data buffer into 464 byte frames
//    {
//      for (int j = 464 * i; j < (464 * i) + 464; j += 58) { //divide the 464 byte frames into 58 byte frames
        byte* f_count=(in_count<58) ? in_count : (in_count / 58) + 1;
        E32.write(f_count,1);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < in_count ; j+=58){
        memcpy(buff, data_buffer + j, 58);
        aes256_encrypt_ecb(&ctxt,buff);
        DUMP("\nEncrypted Data:", i, buff, 58);
        while (digitalRead(AUX) == HIGH) yield(); // wait for the pin to get LOW
        if (digitalRead(AUX) == LOW) { //if the module is READY send
          E32.write(buff, 58);
//          E32.flush();
        }
      }
//    }
    in_count = 0;
    memset(data_buffer, 0x00, BUFFER_SIZE);
    //memset(data_frame, 0x00, ARRAY_SIZE(data_frame));
  }
}
```

Comment: The ESPSoftwareSerial bundled with the esp8266 Arduino boards package supports transmit flow control with `setTransmitEnablePin`

Comment: @Juraj can we use this pin as an input in ESP8266 and hold say 10kB data in buffer until the pin is asserted to given logic and send data as chunks of 512 byte?

Comment: yes the transmit enable pin is an input. you can test `availableForWrite` to check if you can write more data to SoftwareSerial instance

Comment: @Juraj will test this tommorow and will revert back

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. the transmit enable has other purpose (as for RS485) and availableForWrite doesn't work as it should on ESPSoftwareSerial

Comment: Thanks for disclosing @Juraj. Luckily I didn't start test otherwise I would have been breaking my head. I would appreciate If you could help me with defining a function or a statergy to overcome this issue

Comment: it looks like the ESPSoftwareSerial doesn't have internal buffer. so you can simply check the state of the lora pin to decide if you can send.

Comment: @Juraj thats where I am facing a problem The User Manual says`When the module receives the first package from user, the AUX outputs low level. After all the data are transmitted into RF chip and transmission start, the AUX outputs high level At this time , it means that the wireless data package transmission is started, which enables the user to input another 512 bytes continuously`. from this what I understand is I can send data whenever the AUX pin is LOW (in my case is it is HIGH bcoz of transisitor in between).

Comment: So, I tried sending a large byte array say more than 2kB and sniffed with a logic analyzer and I noticed the AUX pin stay continuously LOW even after the first 512 byte and aserts HIGH only 500ms after the TX transmission stopped

Comment: so you should send 512 bytes and then wait until the AUX pin changes from LOW to HIGH, before sending next 512 bytes?

Comment: @Juraj Thats what I understood from the statement given in User manual and tested the hypothesis with logic analyzer but the AUX pin stays low even after sending 512 bytes to the module and only returns HIGH only after 500ms from stopping transmission to the LoRa Module. I don't know is it what its supposed to be then I there is not point in checking at AUX pin and I have to work on something to stop the buffer overflow inside LoRa module and also I need a way for the receiving module to wait until all the send bytes are received and the receive has to send the data all at once through UART